# Can you add a foreign key from a table that you don't have a class model for?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

The table `A` with primary key `Id` exists in the database.
I have a model for class `B`:

```
class B{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int AId{get;set;}
}
```

Can I make `AId` to be a foreign key from table `A` without defining the model for table `A`?

Comment: Do you mean, when using migrations? Otherwise there's no problem.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I've found was to create an empty migration and edit Up and Down methods like this:

```
public partial class BIdFKs : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_B_A",
            table: "dbo.B",
            column: "AId",
            principalTable: "dbo.A",
            principalColumn: "Id"
        );
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_B_A",
            table: "dbo.B"
        );
    }
}
```